# How do I deal with qtbase-abi-5-2-1 dependency on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, dependencies, qt5

I build my c++ Qt app on Mint 17.2, using debuild.  The `$shlibs` variable expands to include `qtbase-abi-5-2-1`.  Does that mean one of the dependent shared libraries is using Qt private headers?  I'm not using private headers explicitly in my app.

In my .pro I have:

```
QT += printsupport
QT += widgets svg xmlpatterns network concurrent
```

Could one of those be causing this dependency?

The problem is my .deb won't install on Ubuntu 15.10 because it can't handle this dependency, since Ubuntu 15.10 comes with a later version of Qt.

Linking Qt statically is not an option for me.  So what options do I have?  Is there some way I can include `libqt5core5a` in my deb, and Ubuntu 15.10 will be happy?  Or if I use a later version of Qt 5 to build, will the dependency on `qtbase-abi-x-x-x` go away (for instance, build on Ubuntu 15.10 which uses Qt 5.4.1 I believe, and future releases of Ubuntu won't complain about `qtbase-abi-5-4-1`)?

**EDIT:**
I tried building on Ubuntu 15.10, and I have the same problem:  the executable is dependent on `qtbase-abi-5-4-2`.

In case it's helpful, I set up my build machine with this:

> sudo apt-get install g++ subversion build-essential devscripts
>   debhelper libicu-dev qtbase5-dev qt5-default libqt5svg5-dev
>   libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev qttools5-dev-tools

Comment: Minor releases a backwards binary compatible, so it's something with the package build process.

Comment: With Qt 4, we didn't have this problem.  I don't think our package build process has changed significantly since porting to Qt 5 - still calling debuild with the same flags, I think, just changed to using Qt 5 qmake in our rules file.  But if I understand you correctly, you're saying if our package build process is correct, we won't have this dependency, right?

Comment: Look what packages depend on qtbase-abi-5-2-1: `apt-cache depends '.*' | egrep 'qtbase-abi-5-2-1|^[^ ]' | grep -B1 qtbase-abi-5-2-1` and what packages depend on libqt5core5a: `apt-cache rdepends libqt5core5a`. The Qt applications depend on libqt5core5a and not on qtbase-abi.

Comment: Thanks:  both commands give me long lists, though the second is much longer than the first.  It appears to me that the Qt stuff depends on both (for example, libqt5widgets5 and qtcreator appear in both lists).  So I'm not sure where to go from here?  If I understand this output correctly (which hopefully I don't), there is no way to build a Qt widget app on Mint 17.2 without static linking, and have it run on Ubuntu 15.10.  Or what am I not understanding?

Comment: QtCreator and Qt libraries are the low level, so they depend on qtbase-abi-x-x-x **directly**. Normal applications don't depend on it directly. They depend on things like libqt5core5a and libqt5widgets5 for example. That's how they are compatible with both distributions.

Comment: Good, that's what I had assumed initially.  So there should be some solution to my problem.  But I'm confused because that's not what I'm seeing:  somehow, when I build my app, my .deb ends up with the qbase-abi-x-x-x dependency.  If I build my app with Qt Creator, is there a way to test the resulting executable to see if it also has that dependency?  Maybe it would be helpful to know whether there's a difference between building with Qt Creator and building with debuild?

Comment: Executables can't have dependencies on the packages, it's a totally different level. Executables depend on the libraries, you can see that with `ldd my_program` (shows the names of the needed libraries and the paths where they've been found on this system). The packages depend on other packages. Open a deb package with an archive extractor and look into the `control` file in the DEBIAN directory: package dependencies are there, not in the executable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101438/discussion-between-david-burson-and-velkan).